# CKEditor apply css to dialog html element contents

Tags: jquery, css, dialog, drupal-7, ckeditor

I have created a ckeditor plugin, the purpose of the plugin is to allow a user to do a lookup of database content and create an html element form that content and insert it into the  editor window.

here is the element definition

```
id: "card_layout",
type: "html",
html: "<h1>Content will display here after selections are made.</h1>" + str,
```

the element is populated after a couple of selections have been made from some dropdowns, but the content has no formatting.

**Question**
How can I apply a style sheet to teh html element so that the content is formatted?

I tried removing the override as

```
this.getElement().removeClass('cke_reset_all')
```

this did not work as expected.

any options of how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The method I use is to place the content inside a div:

```
html: '<div id="content"><h1>Content will display here...</h1></div>'
```

Then in the dialog.css file for the skin you are using you can add the appropriate styles:

```
div#content h1 { font-size: 16pt; }
div#content ul { list-style: circle inside; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else comes across this. The answer (for v4 at least) is to use the 'style' attribute:

```
{
          type: 'button',
          id: 'btnAdd',
          label: 'Add',
          style: 'width:100%;', //Add your styles here just as you would for an inline
          onClick: addTarget
        }
```

Outside of this you can use the onLoad event to add classes to elements, and style from there. [Sauce](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dialog_definition_uiElement.html#property-style)